# How to remove whitespace in SASS string?

Tags: sass

Is there a string function that remove whitespaces in a string in SASS?

For an instance, I'd like to use a variable (string with spaces) to specify a resource image file (name without spaces).

Something like:

```
$str-var: "The White Lion";

@mixin bg-img($name) {
  background-image: url("#{$name}.jpg");
}

.image-cover {
  @include bg-img(str-remove-whitespace($str-var));
}
```

Expected result:

```
.image-cover {
  background-image: url("TheWhiteLion.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such built-in function, but it can be implemented by searching for spaces into string and cutting them out. Something like this should work:

```
@function str-remove-whitespace($str) {
  @while (str-index($str, ' ') != null) {
    $index: str-index($str, ' ');
    $str: "#{str-slice($str, 0, $index - 1)}#{str-slice($str, $index + 1)}";
  }
  @return $str;
}
```

List of available functions you can see into [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html).

Comment: Is not the documentation linked in this answer explicitly says stat `str-slice()`'s index argument starts with 1?