# how to decrease a custom value in time in Sass?

Tags: css, animation, sass

I would like to add a sparkle effect in Sass but I don't know how to use time in order to accelerate the animation : the time between 2 opacity should decrease and when the custom property $time is around 0.1 , stop the animation, I don't know how to do that. Also, with the code below, there's a space between the $time and the "s" for second in the output file in css, is there a way to remove the space automatically?

```
$time: 1*0.9;

@keyframes sparkle {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
.progress {
  animation: sparkle ($time)s infinite alternate;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: For the issue with your `s` being detached you have two options. Add the `s` in the variable `$time: 1*0.9s;` or don't use parentheses use `$time+s` in the animation call.

Comment: Additionally I don't think what you want can be done. Once the CSS is loaded I don't think variable can be changed. They are what they are once loaded. You may have to have `x` number of keyframes and get the percentages closer together as you build the timeline. i.e. 0% 20% 38% 54% 70% 82% 91% 100%.

Comment: @Justin OK great, I cannot upvote because of my points reputation but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the animation so the element remains at `opacity: 0;`, you need to include `forwards` instead of `alternate`.

To gradually speed up the transition, you would probably need to add something that starts with `ease-in` or add some `cubic-bezier` values.
A great test site for this: https://cubic-bezier.com/#.17,.67,.83,.67

To remove any whitespace in `Sass`, you can use functions:

```
@function str-remove-whitespace($str) {
  @while (str-index($str, ' ') != null) {
    $index: str-index($str, ' ');
    $str: "#{str-slice($str, 0, $index - 1)}#{str-slice($str, $index + 1)}";
  }
  @return $str;
}
```

This snippet was taken from: [How to remove whitespace in SASS string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805243/how-to-remove-whitespace-in-sass-string)

```css
@keyframes sparkle {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
.progress {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation: sparkle 2s cubic-bezier(1,.23,.33,.3) forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like to repeat the animation, so that it sparkles, the bezier curve is only for one transition. And I'm not sure how to use the code for the white space, $(time)s gives "0.9 s" instead of "0.9s" in the output file, after Sass was executed.